# Next js not recognizing @lib directory

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I currently have a Next JS project.  In my project I have a directory

```
src
```

In here I have `pages, styles, lib`

in lib I have a file `config.js`

it contains some variables which are exported like so:

```
export { MEDUSA_BACKEND_URL, queryClient, medusaClient }
```

I then attempt to import it into my `_app.js` file

```
import { MEDUSA_BACKEND_URL, queryClient } from "@lib/config"
```

I get an error:

```
./src/pages/_app.js:1:0
Module not found: Can't resolve '@lib/config'
```

I incorrectly assumed that out of the box I could import lib or modules from the directories like so: @lib, @modules
Is there something else I need to add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/module-path-aliases)

You have to create `jsconfig.json` and inside the file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "@pages/*": ["pages/*"],
      "@components/*": ["components/*"],
     
      "@lib/*": ["utils/*"]
    }
  }
}
```